# scrolling view behaviour not working with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am trying to build a screen which when scrolled up will gradually hide the toolbar and on scrolling up, the toolbar will again count down. I am doing something like this(as shown below), but the the toolbar always stays and overlays the content. How can I make it dissappear gradually as we scroll down.

Can you tell me where I am going wrong ?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior=
        "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_side_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_side_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="28dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [revision 23](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes.html) of the [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4), [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) now implements [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html), the interface required to properly send scrolling events to an [AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html).

Update to at least revision 23.0.0 and scrolling the `SwipeRefreshLayout` should properly scroll the `Toolbar`.